# New feature of Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

We have got the new Apple editor Xcode 4, I found some features from the web , but what the new features except the designing and development the Xcode 4 provides ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about reading transition guide and release notes from the apple itself?

Comment: Thats fine , but I want some thing in brief if possible..

Comment: The release notes *are* brief. They're a single-line-per-new-feature list of changes and the answer you accepted is exactly what Eimantas suggested you read in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here '[What's new in Xcode 4](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html)'